# How can I insert one item or list at a position in ROOM DATABASE ANDROID

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

[image]

As you can see in the PIC I've two lists, songs and playlists. So I need to add item or items at a specific position in the ROOM. And for that I've done some steps. like Ive prepared the list first as shown below

```
playlist.add(index, songs.get(position));
```

Also when Im debugging I can see that item is added in the correct index.
But Now Im first clearing the table and then adding the modified PLAYLIST.

But the problem is that newly added item is always written at the end of the playlist table. So where was my mistake? PLEASE HELP! ANY SUGGESTIONS ARE WELCOME.

```
AppExecutors.getInstance().diskIO().execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myDao.clearPlaylist();                // CLEARING DB
                myDao.insertPlaylist(finalMList);     // ADDING NEW LIST
            }
        });
```

Hope you understood what I need! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a column to the playlist for storing the play order and when extracting the playlist `ORDER BY` the play order. However, you then need to re-order the playlist when inserting.

The re-ordering could be handled by an UPDATE prior to the insertion which could be a TRIGGER (noting that Room does not have annotations for defining triggers so you'd have to introduce the TRIGGER via either the onCreate or onOpen callback).

**Without a TRIGGER**

The following demonstrates the technique without using a trigger :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS playlist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS song;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS song (songid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, songname TEXT);
INSERT INTO song (songname) VALUES('Song05'),('Song06'),('Song02'),('Song03'),('Song01'),('Song07'),('Song04');
/*
    song id's will be like:-
    
    Song01 = 5
    Song02 = 3
    Song03 = 4
    Song04 = 7
    Song05 = 1
    Song06 = 2
    Song07 = 6  
*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, songid, play_order);

/* Adding a song to the playlist */

/* Add Song03  as first in playlist */
UPDATE playlist 
    SET play_order = play_order + 1 
        WHERE play_order >= 1 /*order_of_song_to_be_added*/
;
INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (4,1) /* Add Song03  as first in playlist */
;

/* Add Song05 as second */
UPDATE playlist 
SET play_order = play_order + 1 
    WHERE play_order >= 2 /*order_of_song_to_be_added*/
;
INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (1,2) /* Add Song05 as second */
;

/* Add Song07 as third */
UPDATE playlist 
SET play_order = play_order + 1 
    WHERE play_order >= 3 /*order_of_song_to_be_added*/;
INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (6,3) /* Add Song05 as second */
;

/* Add Song05 as third (moves Song07 to fourth) */
UPDATE playlist 
SET play_order = play_order + 1 
    WHERE play_order >= 3 /*order_of_song_to_be_added*/;
INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (5,3) /* Add Song05 as second */
;


/* Add Song06 as first (moves all other songs up 1) */
UPDATE playlist 
SET play_order = play_order + 1 
    WHERE play_order >= 1 /*order_of_song_to_be_added*/;
INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (2,1) /* Add Song05 as second */
;

SELECT play_order, songname 
FROM playlist JOIN song ON song.songid = playlist.songid
ORDER BY play_order;
    
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS playlist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS song;
```

- i.e. whenever inserting then all play_order values greater than or equal to the new play_order are increased by 1 and then the new playlist entry is inserted.

The above results in :-

[image]

The update insert @Dao would be along the lines of :-

```
@Query("UPDATE playlist SET play_order = play_order + 1 WHERE play_order >=:insertion_point")
void prepareForInsertion(long insertion_point);
```

- note the UPDATE would **NOT** be an @Update but an @Query as the convenience @Update isn't suitable.

You would then have something like

```
myDao.clearPlaylist();
for(Playlist p: finalMlist) {
    myDao.prepareForInsertion(p.play_order);
    myDao.insertPlaylist(p);
}
```

or you could have a method in the @Dao class (if it's an abstract class rather than an interface) such as :-

```
@Transaction
@Query("") 
void insertPlaylistEntry(Playlist playlist) {
    prepareForInsertion(p.play_order);
    insertPlaylist(p);
}
```

**With a TRIGGER**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS playlist;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS song;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS song (songid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, songname TEXT);
INSERT INTO song (songname) VALUES('Song05'),('Song06'),('Song02'),('Song03'),('Song01'),('Song07'),('Song04');
/*
    song id's will be like:-
    
    Song01 = 5
    Song02 = 3
    Song03 = 4
    Song04 = 7
    Song05 = 1
    Song06 = 2
    Song07 = 6  
*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlist (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, songid, play_order);
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS playlist_before_insert_reorder 
    BEFORE INSERT ON playlist
    BEGIN
        UPDATE playlist SET play_order = play_order + 1 WHERE play_order >= new.play_order;
    END
;
    
INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (4,1) /* Add Song03  as first in playlist */
;
INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (1,2) /* Add Song05 as second */
;
INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (6,3) /* Add Song05 as second */
;

INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (5,3) /* Add Song05 as second */
;

INSERT INTO playlist (songid,play_order) VALUES
    (2,1) /* Add Song05 as second */
;

SELECT play_order, songname 
FROM playlist JOIN song ON song.songid = playlist.songid
ORDER BY play_order;
```

As you can see the trigger does it's work :-

[image]

**Working Example using Trigger**

**Song** :-

```
@Entity(tableName = Song.TABLE_NAME)
class Song {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "song";
    public static final String COL_ID = TABLE_NAME+"id";
    public static final String COL_SONGNAME = TABLE_NAME+"_name";
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_ID)
    Long id = null;
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_SONGNAME)
    String name;

    Song(){}
    @Ignore
    Song(String name) {
        this.id = null;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Playlist** :-

```
@Entity(
        tableName = Playlist.TABLE_NAME,
        foreignKeys = {
                @ForeignKey(
                        entity = Song.class,
                        parentColumns = Song.COL_ID,
                        childColumns = Playlist.COL_SONG_MAP,
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                        onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
                )
        }
)
class Playlist {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "playlist";
    public static final String COL_ID = TABLE_NAME+"id";
    public static final String COL_SONG_MAP = TABLE_NAME+"_"+Song.TABLE_NAME+"_map";
    public static final String COL_PLAY_ORDER = TABLE_NAME+"_play_order";

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_ID)
    Long id = null;
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_SONG_MAP, index = true)
    long songid;
    @ColumnInfo(name = COL_PLAY_ORDER, index = true)
    long play_order;

    Playlist(){}
    @Ignore
    Playlist(long songid, long play_order){
        this.id = null;
        this.songid = songid;
        this.play_order = play_order;
    }
}
```

**PlaylistWithSong** POJO to get both together

```
class PlaylistWithSong {
    @Embedded
    Playlist playlist;
    @Embedded
    Song song;
}
```

**AllDao**

```
@Dao
abstract class AllDao {

    @Insert
    abstract long insert(Song song);
    @Insert
    abstract long insert(Playlist playList);
    @Insert
    abstract long[] insertSongs(List<Song> songList);
    @Insert
    abstract long[] insertPlaylists(List<Playlist> playListList);
    @Query("DELETE FROM " + Playlist.TABLE_NAME)
    abstract int clearPLayList();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM " + Playlist.TABLE_NAME +
            " JOIN " + Song.TABLE_NAME +
            " ON " + Song.TABLE_NAME + "." + Song.COL_ID + "=" + Playlist.TABLE_NAME + "." + Playlist.COL_SONG_MAP +
            " ORDER BY " + Playlist.COL_PLAY_ORDER + " ASC")
    abstract List<PlaylistWithSong> getOrderedPlayList();
}
```

**TheDatabase** the @Database class :-

```
@Database(entities = {Song.class,Playlist.class},version = 1)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDao getAllDao();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance = null;
    static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context, TheDatabase.class,"thedatabase.db"
            )
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .addCallback(CALLBACK)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    /*
        CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS playlist_before_insert_reorder
            BEFORE INSERT ON playlist
            BEGIN
                UPDATE playlist SET play_order = play_order + 1 WHERE play_order >= new.play_order;
            END
        ;
     */
    private static final String playlist_reorder_trigger =
            "CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS " + Playlist.COL_PLAY_ORDER + "_before_insert_reorder " +
                    "BEFORE INSERT ON " + Playlist.TABLE_NAME + " BEGIN " +
                    "UPDATE " + Playlist.TABLE_NAME + " " +
                    "SET " + Playlist.COL_PLAY_ORDER + "=" + Playlist.COL_PLAY_ORDER + " + 1 " +
                    "WHERE " + Playlist.COL_PLAY_ORDER + " >= new." + Playlist.COL_PLAY_ORDER +";" +
                    "END;";

    static RoomDatabase.Callback CALLBACK = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            db.execSQL(playlist_reorder_trigger);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
            /* Just in case not created in onCreate e.g. migration */
            db.execSQL(playlist_reorder_trigger);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestructiveMigration(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onDestructiveMigration(db);
        }
    };
}
```

**Finally**

An Activity that demonstrates the asnwer above :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDao dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDao();

        long s5id = dao.insert(new Song("Song05"));
        long s6id = dao.insert(new Song("Song06"));
        long s2id = dao.insert(new Song("Song02"));
        long s3id = dao.insert(new Song("Song03"));
        long s1id = dao.insert(new Song("Song01"));
        long s7id = dao.insert(new Song("Song07"));
        long s4id = dao.insert(new Song("Song04"));

        List<Playlist> playlistList = Arrays.asList(
                new Playlist(s3id,1),
                new Playlist(s5id,2),
                new Playlist(s7id,3),
                new Playlist(s1id,3),
                new Playlist(s6id,1));

        dao.clearPLayList();
        dao.insertPlaylists(playlistList);
        for (PlaylistWithSong p: dao.getOrderedPlayList()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","Song is " + p.song.name + " play order is " + p.playlist.play_order);
        }
    }
}
```

that is:-

1. adds some songs (pseudo indiscriminately regarding order)
2. creates a playlist as a Playlist Array with the play order.
3. inserts the playlist
4. extracts the playlist and outputs the songs in the anticipated order as per

:-

```
2021-12-01 08:41:49.706 D/DBINFO: Song is Song06 play order is 1
2021-12-01 08:41:49.706 D/DBINFO: Song is Song03 play order is 2
2021-12-01 08:41:49.706 D/DBINFO: Song is Song05 play order is 3
2021-12-01 08:41:49.707 D/DBINFO: Song is Song01 play order is 4
2021-12-01 08:41:49.707 D/DBINFO: Song is Song07 play order is 5
```

- i.e. Song07 originally inserted at order 3 has been moved to order 5 because a) the insertion of Song01 at 3 moved Song07 to 4 and then b) the insertion of Song06 at 1 moved all from (1-4) to (2-5).

**Comments**

> Im not maintaining PLAY_ORDER.

If you want a play order as you describe, then you have to maintain one, it will not come from nowhere and hence why you are getting the results you have shown.

> But while inserting into the ROOM DB new item is written at the end of the table. why?

There is no concept of at the front, end or in between. When you extract data you use ORDER BY (column or columns) if you don't specify an ORDER then the ORDER will be as SQLite deems (which will often be via the Primary Key). As such for your case you NEED a column that indicates the ORDER that you want (the play order).

**If** the table (Playlist) has an alias of the rowid (a single column for the primary key which has an integer type) then the value of that column, if not specifically set will typically be 1 greater than the highest value of the column (1 if no other rows).

Furthermore if you have specified `autogenerate = true` (which equates to SQLite's [AUTOINCREMENT](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)), then that value will be 1 or more greater than the highest **ever used value** and hence if you delete all rows and the Playlist, that overtime has had 103 rows inserted then the next row will be 104, even though it is the only row.

- using `autogenerate = true` aka `AUTOINCREMENT`, as per the link, is virtually definitely not required and is therefore virtually definitely inefficient.

If you have `autogenerate = false` (implied by not specifying `autogenerate = true`) then if all rows are deleted the first value will be 1 (most likely).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Im not maintaining PLAY_ORDER. I just have a list. So when Im inserting item in a list, its actually there. But while inserting into the ROOM DB new item is written at the end of the table. why?

Comment: Lets say we have playlist[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  Now we want to add one item in the list like this playlist[1, 2, 104, 3, 4, 5]  So here 104 is the new item. And like in this order I need save that entire list. But 104 always writes at the end index of ROOM TABLE. Please explain why.

Comment: @SubhojitHalder Explanation  is because you are implying an order that is the insertion order and that you are not specifying an order. Nor having a column that suits the order that you want.

Comment: I didn't get it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your complete explanation. I just achieved what I needed! So What I did is just resetting the _ID (primary_key) by setID of MODEL class inside a FOR LOOP.  And Now ROOM is able to store my ordered list. Thanks again. This was a great Q.